# MVC Partial View Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to understand partial views in MVC...
What I am trying to accomplish is to have a master View which renders, say, two partial views.
Each partial view contains a different ViewModel (with DataAnnotations). When I submit the form of one of those partial views, in case there is a server-side validation error, I would like to have the master View show up again with the validation messages on that partial.

Any tips in the right way would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: "I would like to have the master View show up again with the validation messages on that partial." what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean the master page would be displayed again with the proper validation messages.

Comment: Have you tried unobtrusive client side validation. This should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with the sample solution -

Let create a complex model in following way -

```
public class Person
{
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
    public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then lets create a Main controller with an Index action in following way, this action is going to create a simple dummy model and bind it to the Index view -

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           Person p = new Person();
           p.contact = new Contact();
           p.vehicle = new Vehicle();
           return View(p);
       }
}
```

And Index view is going to be -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit","Main",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.contact, "~/Views/Main/EditorTemplates/Contact.cshtml")
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.vehicle, "~/Views/Main/EditorTemplates/Vehicle.cshtml")    
    <input type="submit" value="click"/>
}
```

Here in the above view, instead of using Partial Views, I used Editor Views. Reason is that Partial views gives very hard experience in Model binding the Complex models.

So I created EditorTemplated folder in Main View folder and placed following files in there.

Contact.cshtml -

```
@model MVC.Controllers.Contact

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
```

Vehicle.cshtml -

@model MVC.Controllers.Vehicle

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

With the above setup, we can go and run the application and following screen should show up -

[image]

And this form is going to POSTed to Submit Action of Main controller, so this is going to be my submit action -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(Person p)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Index", p);
        else
        {
            // do something
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When we click button without entering any value, then validation will trigger and we should see error messages as below -

[image]

And in normal valid situations, you can submit the form and then run your business logic.